# liblinear L1 vs. L2 logistic regression performance difference

Tags: machine-learning, regression, liblinear

I'm training a simple logistic regression classifier using LIBLINEAR. There are only 3 features, and label is binary 0-1.

Sample input file:

```
1   1:355.55660999775586    2:-3.401379785      3:5
1   1:252.43759050148728    2:-3.96044759307    3:9
1   1:294.15085871437088    2:-13.1649273486    3:14
1   1:432.10492221032933    2:-2.72636786196    3:9
0   1:753.80863694081768    2:-12.4841741178    3:14
1   1:376.54927850355756    2:-6.9494008935     3:7
```

Now, if I use "-s 6", which is "**L1-regularized logistic regression**", then the 10-fold cross validation accuracy is around 70%, and each iter finishes within seconds. 
But if I use "-s 7", which is "**L2-regularized logistic regression (dual)**", then the training iteration exceeds 1000, and the 10-fold accuracy is only 60%.

Has anybody seen this kind of strange behavior? From my understanding, the only difference between L1 and L2 is whether the regularization term uses abs(x) or pow(x, 2).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this! I work with liblinear fairly often and generally always use L2 loss without thinking. This article does a pretty good job explaining the difference: http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-l1-and-l2-as-loss-function-and-regularization/

Based on that, I'm guessing that not only do you have a small amount of features but maybe also a small dataset? Have you tried to increase the number of input points?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have around 300000 training examples, among which 64% are positive training examples. Do you think this is enough?

Comment: BTW, very helpful article!

Comment: Happy the article helped! 
Oh yea that should way more than enough, and the skew shouldn't be big enough to make that much of a difference. Have you tried standard things like perhaps regularizing the input data? Can you plot the error as a function of training iterations? Maybe it doesn't converge?

Answer (score 0):

Not think it's a 'Strange' behavior in my poor opinion. You have to make a trial to confirm which one is fitted into your case better before you have not any sense of it. Theoretically,L1-regular is bounded,just like feature selection,while l2-regular is more smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized there are two logistic regression classifier provided by LIBLINEAR:

```
0 -- L2-regularized logistic regression (primal)
7 -- L2-regularized logistic regression (dual)
```

I was using 7, which doesn't converge even after 1000 iterations. 
After I switched to 0, it converged very fast and was able to get to ~70% accuracy.

I believe the dual vs. primal is mainly the difference in optimization methods, so I think this is probably some numerical computation issue.

For more info on dual form vs. primal form:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29059/logistic-regression-how-to-get-dual-function